# How to fetch all items in array?

Tags: mysql

Im confused on how to fetch all of the stuff in my array... Its like a table from a SQL.. I can get one of them doing the following:

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `todoTable` WHERE 1")) {
printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", mysqli_num_rows($result));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[0];
mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

But when i try to do all of it... It fails..

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `todotable` WHERE 1")) {
     printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", mysqli_num_rows($result));
     // Fetch all
    $row = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo $row;

    mysqli_free_result($result);
  }
```

Please Help.. Thankyou

Comment: **WHERE 1** makes me confused too

Comment: That dosent matter... @HermanNz It returns all the stuff. Same thing if i didnt put it there

Comment: I usually write variable, e.g. email=, etc to create array

Comment: *"But when i try to do all of it... It fails.."* - does it give an error?

Comment: Yes it does @ʰᵈˑ It says that its an array so you have to make it a string..

Comment: Then use a loop to iterate through the array, or use `json_encode()` if you want a string. `print_r($row);` to see the structure.

Comment: Thanks @ʰᵈˑ but this is what i get Array ( [0] => Array ( [Todo] => SomeToDoList )  Including multiple others buthow do i get the SomeToDoList?

Comment: `echo $row[0]['Todo'];` will do that - but you'd need a loop otherwise change your query to add a limit clause to only fetch 1 record.

Comment: [Use concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: Understand @ʰᵈˑ thanks so much for helping me. Posted anwser below to help other users..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using foreach to iterate through the array, I usually get what I want using that method.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach($row as $value)
     echo $value;
```